# Convergent or divergent?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^0 \frac1{(1+x)^e} \,dx$$

I have tried using integral test and got an answer of converges with answer of 
$$\frac1{1-e}$$

is the correct?

And also for
$$\int_1^∞ e^{-2x} \, dx$$ 
that i tried using integration test as well with answer of 
$$\frac {-e^{-2}}2$$ 
which converges

Everything doesnt look right and please do advice, thank you.

I have also tried comparison test for both question where both are found to be 
∞ (therefore diverges). However, when bigger function diverges, smaller function cannot diverge hence inconclusive. Am i doing it right?

Comment: The first one diverges but the second converges. Show us how you used the test so we could see what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just straightforward computations: $$\int_{-1}^0 \frac{{\rm d}x}{(1+x)^e} = \lim_{c \to -1}\int_c^0 \frac{{\rm d}x}{(1+x)^e} = \lim_{c \to -1} \frac{(1+x)^{1-e}}{1-e}\Big|_c^0 = +\infty,$$ because of the limit $$\lim_{c \to -1} \frac{1}{(1+c)^{e-1}} = +\infty.$$ For the next one: $$\int_1^{+\infty} e^{-2x}\,{\rm d}x = \lim_{c \to +\infty}\int_1^ce^{-2x}\,{\rm d}x = \lim_{c \to +\infty}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}\Big|_1^c = \frac{1}{2e^2}.$$You just got a sign wrong there in the end, but the integral converges.

Comment: i'm wondering why is it 1/2e instead of 1/2e^-2 for the second question, mind explaining?

Comment: I got it wrong, it is 1/2e^-2, really. I am positive about the sign, though. Thanks for pointing.